# VPN Windows 2012 r2 Resources (share drivers or rdp connection) not available after connection

Tags: routes, vpn, windows-server-2012

I hope everyone is keeping safe!!. I was wondering if I can get some pointers into an issue that I have been experiencing for a day or so now. I am trying to implement a VPN solution so that people now working from home can access some very specific share drivers and also being able to rdp to their own machines.
The server has been running for years and it has two NICs, but the nicss are for redundancy and balance only (both nics are connecting to the firewall and router facing the internet, please do not kill the messenger, that is how it has been working for ages and no it was not me).
I followed the instructions in order to install the VPN Routing and Remote Access. I also implemented the Network Policy Server to allow MS-Chap V2 (extensible authentication protocol (EAP)) connection.
I started the service and it seems working fine as I can VPN to the machine from the wan outside, the laptop obtain the "correct" IP from the dhcp server and I can see the laptop in the remote Access clients, however I can not access the share drivers (they have a red x on the drive and upon click I get the "An error occurred while reconnecting..." and also RDP to the local machines takes me no where. I believe the setup is okay but I also think I am missing a route somewhere or setting. I have been reading everywhere and change lots of the setup including adding the Ipv4 router (Local are network(LAN) routing only), etc, etc but no Joy, also I have to admit that routing and routes are not my strong point hence I am a bit loss. 
Any help will be appreciated.
(below some screenshots of what I think can be useful infor but please let me know if you need more )
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

ip-routing in both nics looks like
[image]
the routing in the laptop looks like
[image]
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the whole Remote Control and reinstall, that somehow did the trick